# If $f(y\mid\theta)\sim N(\theta, 1)$, how to find the asymptotic distribution $f\left(y\mid\hat{\theta}_n^{MLE}\right)$?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, normal-distribution

If I have that $f(y\mid\theta)$ has a $N(\theta, 1)$ distribution, and $\widehat{\theta}_n^{MLE} \to \theta^{\star}$ in probability, where $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \sim N(\theta^{\star},1)$, how can I find the asymptotic distribution of $p\left(y\mid\widehat{\theta}_n^{MLE}\right)$?

I know that we should have $N\left(\widehat{\theta}_n^{MLE},1\right)$ converging to $N\left(\theta^{\star},1\right)$ but am not sure how to show this. Does anyone have any ideas?